# Iterating through a multidimensional array and adding in floats

Tags: c

The point of the program is to iterate through a multidimensional array, adding in the floating point numbers into rainFall. For the most part the program works but what I can't figure out is that through the first iteration, row 0, none of the floating point numbers are being added in. I'm sure it's something super simple that I missed since I'm fairly new to C.

```
int main()
{
    int i, j;
    float rainFall = 0.0;
    float weather[5][12] =
                {{2010, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1,1.1,1.1,1.1,1.1,1.1,1.1,1.1},
                {2011,1.1, 1.1, 1.1,1.1,1.1,1.1,1.1,1.1,1.1,1.1},
                {2012,1.1, 1.1, 1.1,1.1,1.1,1.1,1.1,1.1,1.1,1.1},
                {2013,1.1, 1.1, 1.1,1.1,1.1,1.1,1.1,1.1,1.1,1.1},
                {2014,1.1, 1.1, 1.1,1.1,1.1,1.1,1.1,1.1,1.1,1.1},

    };

    //  outer loop iterates through years
    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        printf("%.f\n", weather[i][0]);
        printf("Average rainfall is %.2f\n", rainFall);
        rainFall = 0;
        //  inner loop iterates through months
        //  adds in to rainFall average
        for(j = 1; j < 12; j++)
        {
            rainFall += weather[i][j] / 12;
        }
     }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Time to do a little [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging)... Where are you printing the average? Where are you calculating the average?

Comment: Here is a little more on useful debugging, it includes the hitn by Some. https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude The year and average are printed in the outer loop. The calculation for the average is being done in the inner loop before being added to rainFall

Comment: Yeah, that's generally what happens when you print results before you calculate them.

Comment: I figured it out. I added the printf line for the average rain fall after the inner loop. I knew it was something simple that I just wasn't seeing. Thank you everyone for your input.

Comment: Since you keep the year in the zero-th element, you need 12+1 entries for each row. And I only count ten (10) month entries, so, you really should allocate each row as float[1+12], and since you have five (5) years, weather[5][1+12]. But keeping the year as a float is odd.

Comment: OT:  a literal, like: `1.1` is a `double` value.  However, the table is declared as `float`.  To write a float literal, use a trailing `f`, as in: `1.1f`   and the `divide by 12` is dividing a `float` value by an integer.  Suggest: `/ 12.0f`

Comment: The posted code does not cleanly compile! It is missing the  needed `#include` statement for the needed header file,  When posting a question about a run time problem, as this is doing, always post a [mcve] so we can reproduce the problem and help you debug it.

Comment: Strongly suggest creating a `struct RAIN { int year; float monthRain[12]; );` then making an array of those sturcts  One more detail:  the code contains 'magic' numbers, 5, 12.  'magic' numbers are numbers with no basis.  'magic' numbers make the code much more difficult to understand, debug, etc.  Suggest giving those 'magic' numbers  meaningful names via `#define` statements.  Then using those meaningful names throughout the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, it looks like your weather matrix represents info for a year on each row. The first item is the year number, and the other elements are the information for each month. Since a year has 12 months, it seems fine to me to change it to 
`weather[5][13]`
Even so, when you set the values for weather, you only typed it for 10 months on each line, so the matrix would not be complete.

Lastly, you should calculate the average BEFORE printing its value. In the way you made, you are "missing by one", and showing the average value from the row calculated in the last iteration. The first iteration you will print the 0 right away. The code with the changes I suggested follow:

```
int main()
{
    int i, j;
    float rainFall = 0.0;
    float weather[5][13] =
                {
//      year, 01   02   03  04  05  06  07  08  09  10  11  12
        {2010,1.1, 1.1, 1.1,1.1,1.1,1.1,1.1,1.1,1.1,1.1,1.1,1.1},
        {2011,1.1, 1.1, 1.1,1.1,1.1,1.1,1.1,1.1,1.1,1.1,1.1,1.1},
        {2012,1.1, 1.1, 1.1,1.1,1.1,1.1,1.1,1.1,1.1,1.1,1.1,1.1},
        {2013,1.1, 1.1, 1.1,1.1,1.1,1.1,1.1,1.1,1.1,1.1,1.1,1.1},
        {2014,1.1, 1.1, 1.1,1.1,1.1,1.1,1.1,1.1,1.1,1.1,1.1,1.1},

    };

    //  outer loop iterates through years
    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        rainFall = 0;
        //  inner loop iterates through months
        //  adds in to rainFall average
        for(j = 1; j < 13; j++)
        {
            rainFall += weather[i][j] / 12;
        }
        printf("%.f\n", weather[i][0]);
        printf("Average rainfall is %.2f\n", rainFall);
     }

    return 0;
}
```

Which gives the expected output:

```
2010
Average rainfall is 1.10
2011
Average rainfall is 1.10
2012
Average rainfall is 1.10
2013
Average rainfall is 1.10
2014
Average rainfall is 1.10
```

Sure, to visualize this kind of problem you could have tested it with different expected values for different years, so you would see "off-by-one" I mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Since you keep the year (an integer) in the zero-th element, you need 12+1 (13) elements of each row. My suggestion would be to store the year in the last position (rather than the first), to reduce accidental errors. Keeping the year stored as a float is unusual. You might consider storing rainfall as 'fixed-point' integer, where you would scale the numbers manually (this would reduce the accumulation of numerical errors, if you can decide a minimum resolution of the measurements).

Since you have 5 years, I suggest that you declare your rainfall 2D array using contants (or #defines) as YEARS, MONTHS,

```
float weather[YEARS][1+MONTHS];
```

You really need to allocate each row as float[1+12] (putting the 1 first to hint to the next developer, or a future you, that something different is being done.

```
#define YEARS (5)
#define MONTHS (12)

int main()
{
    int year, month;
    float rainFall = 0.0, avg_rainFall = 0.0;
    float weather[YEARS][1+MONTHS] = {
          {2010, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1}
         ,{2011, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1}
         ,{2012, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1}
         ,{2013, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1}
         ,{2014, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1}
    };

    //  outer loop iterates through years
    for(year= 0; year < YEARS; year++)
    {
        printf("%.f\n", weather[year][0]);
        printf("Average rainfall is %.2f\n", rainFall);
        total_rainFall = 0;
        //  inner loop iterates through months
        //  adds in to rainFall average
        for(month = 0; month < MONTHS; month++)
        {
            rainFall += weather[year][1+month];
        }
        avg_rainFall = rainFall / MONTHS;
     }

    return 0;
}
```

The accumulation of rainFall for a year is accumulated, then the average is calculated. This reduces accumulation of small floating point numerical errors (see: numerical analysis). This also reduces the number of divisions by a factor of 12 (not important here, but very important when you are working with large datasets).

Comment: I'd suggest using `enum { YEARS = 5 }; enum { MONTHS = 12 };` rather than `#define` for the symbolic constants, as a good habit someone can pick up early in their learning progress. The enumerators will be handled like other identifiers (respecting scope and visibility for example)

Answer (score 0):

Restructuring your data into a format better serving you needs can help reduce some of the complexities in the code. This takes it form a multidimensional array to a structured array instead.

And unless you using C90, try not to declare your variables before you need them.

In my proposed changes, the numerical data is also changed to the types they represent. `const` is added to declare that this data does not change. `double` used to minimize risk of rounding errors. Year in now represented as a integer instead of a float thanks to the data structure used.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

enum { MONTHS = 12 };

struct Data {
  int year;
  float monthRain[MONTHS];
};

int main(void) {
  enum { YEARS = 5 };
  struct Data const weather[YEARS] = 
      {{2010, {1.1f, 1.1f, 1.1f, 1.1f, 1.1f, 1.1f, 1.1f, 1.1f, 1.1f, 1.1f, 1.1f, 1.1f}},
       {2011, {1.2f, 1.2f, 1.2f, 1.2f, 1.2f, 1.2f, 1.2f, 1.2f, 1.2f, 1.2f, 1.2f, 1.2f}},
       {2012, {1.3f, 1.3f, 1.3f, 1.3f, 1.3f, 1.3f, 1.3f, 1.3f, 1.3f, 1.3f, 1.3f, 1.3f}},
       {2013, {1.4f, 1.4f, 1.4f, 1.4f, 1.4f, 1.4f, 1.4f, 1.4f, 1.4f, 1.4f, 1.4f, 1.4f}},
       {2014, {1.5f, 1.5f, 1.5f, 1.5f, 1.5f, 1.5f, 1.5f, 1.5f, 1.5f, 1.5f, 1.5f, 1.5f}}};

  //  outer loop iterates through years
  for (int yearIndex = 0; yearIndex < YEARS; yearIndex++) {
    double totalRainFallInYear = 0.0;
    //  inner loop iterates through months
    for (int monthIndex = 0; monthIndex < MONTHS; monthIndex++) {
      totalRainFallInYear += weather[yearIndex].monthRain[monthIndex];
    }
    double const avgRainFallPerMonth = totalRainFallInYear / (double)MONTHS;
    printf("Year %d\nAverage rainfall is %.2f\n", weather[yearIndex].year,
           avgRainFallPerMonth);
  }

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```